# How to count occurrences of a word/token in a one-token-per-document-per-row tibble

Tags: r, text-mining

Hello I have a tibble through a pipe from `tidytext::unnest_tokens()` and `count(category, word, name = "count")`. It looks like this example.

```
owl <- tibble(category = c(0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 2),
              word = c(rep("hello", 3), rep("world", 4)),
              count = sample(1:100, 7))
```

and I would like to get this tibble with an additional column that gives the number of categories the word appears in, i.e. the same number for each time the word appears.

I tried the following code that works in principal. The result is what I want.

```
owl %>% mutate(sum_t = sapply(1:nrow(.), function(x) {filter(., word == .$word[[x]]) %>% nrow()}))
```

However, seeing that my data has 10s of thousands of rows this takes a rather long time. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `owl %>% group_by(word) %>% mutate(n = n())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `add_count`:

```
library(dplyr)

 owl %>% 
   add_count(word)
```

output:

```
  category word  count     n
     <dbl> <chr> <int> <int>
1        0 hello    98     3
2        1 hello    30     3
3        2 hello    37     3
4       -1 world    22     4
5        0 world    80     4
6        1 world    18     4
7        2 world    19     4
```

Comment: oh wow I'm blind. totally missed add_count in the count documentation. Works perfectly and super fast. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I played around with a few solutions and microbenchmark. I added TarJae's proposition to the benchmark. I also wanted to use the fantastic `ave` function just to see how it would compare to a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 500

owl2 <- tibble(
  category = sample(-10:10, n , replace = TRUE),
  word = sample(stringi::stri_rand_strings(5, 10), n, replace = TRUE),
  count = sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE))

mb <- microbenchmark(
  op = owl2 %>% mutate(sum_t = sapply(1:nrow(.), function(x) {filter(., word == .$word[[x]]) %>% nrow()})),
  group_by = owl2 %>% group_by(word) %>% mutate(n = n()), 
  add_count = owl2 %>% add_count(word), 
  ave = cbind(owl2, n = ave(owl2$word, owl2$word, FUN = length)), 
  times = 50L)

autoplot(mb) + theme_bw()
```

The conclusion is that the elegant solution using `add_count` will save you a lot of time, and, ave speeds up a lot the process.

[image: Benchmark]

Comment: thanks a lot for this! as i don't know ave I'll stick with the tidy verse solution, but good to keep in mind if ever true enormous data sets cross my path